# Does chroot make effect on bootable usb-pendrive?

Tags: linux, bootable-media, chroot, chroot-jail

Let's suppose I put my Linux usb-pendrive inside my PC. I start the system and the I use **chroot** to apply same changes to the system.

What happen if I reboot the usb-pendrive? Are the changes I made persistent, or do I have to chroot again?

Comment: Non-boot  drives don't have persistent permissions. You can simply switch them off/ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

If you:

1. Boot linux USB
2. Mount internal HDD
3. Chroot to that HDD and make changes

In this case changes made on mounted HDD will be permanent.
This scheme is useful for restoring bootloader for example.